# How to transfer mysql's 1 million records from one machine to another without affecting performance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am generating unique tokes for different clients. for every client request i have to generate 1 million unique tokens. generating unique tokens takes long time hence i am performing this activity in a background using delayed job gem.

```
Flow of my application is as below
1) Client machine sends an api request to remote server to generate 1 million unique tokens.Remote machine sends response back to client machine with status "pending" and start generating 1 million unqiue tokens. 

2)After generating 1 million unique token for a request remote server sends these unique tokens back to the client machine using an API call. 

3)client machine stores these unique tokens in his database using delayed job.
```

But the problem is that whenever i hit more than 5 request simultaneously that time mysql is closing the connection with error "mysql server has gone away: mysql closed connection issue" and hence not able to generate unique tokens.

So i want to know how to generate and transfer this unique tokens(1 million records) in a efficient way  form remote server to client machine without affecting performance.

Thanks,

Comment: 1. When you are generating tokens on remote server, how are they stored in memory or some db? 2. When you are sending 1 million records back to client are u sending all of them at once or in batches?

Comment: 1. They are stored in db.   2)i am sending all of them at once.. tokens need to be stored on remote as well as client machine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its a good idea to send all record at once. What if connection between client and server is lost? Data transfer needs to be started all over again?

I think you should build an API call which delivers unique token in batch i.e excepts limit and offset.

1. On successful generation of 1 million tokens on remote server just send success response to client.
2. Client can request data/token in batch by providing limit and offset. It will also help you to keep track of how much tokens are loaded on client side and how much left.
3. Repeat step 2 until everything gets loaded to client side. In case of failure you can request only that chunk of data / batch again.

Regarding mysql issue:

1. Try to load tokens using bulk insert that is also preferred in batches. `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);`
2. Try to tweak my sql configuration for performance enhancement. [This](https://major.io/2008/06/24/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connections/) can be a good read.

Let me know if this helps. Thanks!